# Unclear Application of Cauchy's Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was looking for a solution to a problem (both found [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1349005&sid=bf18d35319f87a9335fd9aec9a200dac#p1349005)), where I came across the following ($a, b, c > 0$):

> Applying Cauchy's inequality, we get
>   $(\frac{c}{a+2b} + \frac{a}{b+2c} + \frac{b}{c+2a})(3(ab + bc + ca)) \geq (a + b + c)^2$

I understand that each of the three terms in both the `sequences' on the left is a square, but then how would that simplify to something as clean as the right-hand side? Wouldn't it at least involve some square roots?

I will be grateful if someone can explain this to me. I know I am wrong, but I can't seem to find *where*. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the terms of $3(ab+bc+ca)$ as

$$(ca + 2bc) + (ab + 2ac) + (bc + 2ab) = c(a+2b) + a(b+2c) + b(c + 2a)$$

and pair them with

$$\frac{c}{a+2b} + \frac{a}{b+2c} + \frac{b}{c+2a}.$$

We have

$$\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+2b}}\cdot \sqrt{c(a+2b)} = c$$

etc.